# Equivalent of let-alist for plists?

Tags: property-lists

I'm curious if there's an equivalent for `let-alist` for plists.  Namely, a macro for accessing plists in the manner that alists may be accessed as:

```
(let-alist alist
  (if (and .title .body)
      .body
    .site
    .site.contents))
```

It would probably be necessary to translate keyword symbols, of course, so a plist like the following may be accessed:

```
(my/let-plist '(:foo "bar" :baz "bat")
  (if (equal .foo "bar")
      .baz
    "default"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't difficult to make your own `let-plist` by referring to `let-alist.el`, here is my attempt, the mainly difference is `let-plist--list-to-sexp`.

```el
(require 'let-alist)

(defun let-plist--list-to-sexp (list var)
  "Turn symbols LIST into recursive calls to `plist-get' on VAR."
  `(plist-get ,(if (cdr list)
                   (let-plist--list-to-sexp (cdr list) var)
                   var)
              ',(intern (concat ":" (symbol-name (car list))))))

(defun let-plist--access-sexp (symbol variable)
  "Return a sexp used to access SYMBOL inside VARIABLE."
  (let* ((clean (let-alist--remove-dot symbol))
         (name (symbol-name clean)))
    (if (string-match "\\`\\." name)
        clean
        (let-plist--list-to-sexp
         (mapcar #'intern (nreverse (split-string name "\\.")))
         variable))))

(defmacro let-plist (plist &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1))
  (let ((var (make-symbol "plist")))
    `(let ((,var ,plist))
       (let ,(mapcar (lambda (x) `(,(car x) ,(let-plist--access-sexp (car x) var)))
                     (delete-dups (let-alist--deep-dot-search body)))
         ,@body))))
```

Here are some uses.

```el
(let-plist '(:foo 1 :bar 2)
  .bar)
;; => 2

(let-plist '(:question (:title
                        "Equivalent of let-alist for plists?"
                        :id
                        "45581"
                        :tags
                        ("property-lists")))
  .question.title)
;; => "Equivalent of let-alist for plists?"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
(pcase-defmacro plist (&rest args)
  `(and (pred listp)
        ,@(mapcar (lambda (elt)
                    (if (consp elt)
                        `(app (pcase--flip plist-get ,(car elt)) ,(cadr elt))
                      `(app (pcase--flip plist-get ',elt)
                            ,(if (keywordp elt)
                                 (intern (substring (symbol-name elt) 1))
                               elt))))
                  args)))
```

after which you can do

```
(pcase-let (((plist :key val) `(:key 4 val 5)))
  (+ key val))
```

or

```
(pcase-let (((plist (:key k) ('val v)) `(:key 4 val 5)))
  (+ k v))
```

The code was an adaptation of the `map` pcase pattern (which can be used for alists, hash-tables, and arrays).

Comment: Thanks; this is so cool!  I frequently use the `-let*` destructuring sugar for alists/plists `(-let* (((&plist :some-prop some-prop) my-plist)) ...)` and the notion of custom/extensible destructuring never occurred to me!  The syntax is a little verbose for my taste though (hence the question).

Comment: @ebpa: Extensibility and generality come at a cost in terms of conciseness, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The option that I have resorted to previously is converting the plist to an alist using the `kv` package (`kvplist->alist`):

```
(let-alist (kvplist->alist '(:foo "bar" :baz (:bat "blah"))
  .foo)
```

However, this only addresses the shallow case; it doesn't offer nested access via `.baz.bat`.